# Admin accounts migration in magento 2 from magento 1 website

Tags: magento2-migration-tool, magento2.3.0

Is there any way to migrate magento 1 admin accounts with access privilege to magento 2.3. Because on magento website, they have mention to do it manually but password algorithm is changed. So if i created accounts manually by copying data from Db, it is not working.

Any help would be appreciated.

Thanks!

Answer (score 0):

You can view account info from old site.
After that, create account with same info via command:

```
bin/magento admin:user:create --admin-user="admin" --admin-password="123123q" --admin-email="admin@example.com" --admin-firstname="Admin" --admin-lastname="Admin"
```

Last step, please coppy password of old account and paste to new account in table: "admin_passwords" column "password_hash"

```
Flush cache: bin/magento c:f
```

Goodluk!

Comment: From admin how could you know password of the admin user which i need to enter in the command.  And as i mentioned above, i tried copying password from m1 to m2 but it is not working on m2 admin panel. have you tried your way at your end once.

Comment: did you access to database or ssh? you can copy from it